Convolution in Fourier space with Python
I am trying to implement following step into the my cosmological particle mesh code.

From the PM code, I obtained the 3D array for density and used the following code in python, but I'm not sure, if this solution is correct
def Conv_dens( density, sigma, n_cells ):
n_x = np.linspace(0,n_cells-1,n_cells)
n_y = np.linspace(0,n_cells-1,n_cells)
n_z = np.linspace(0,n_cells-1,n_cells)
k_x = n_x * (2*np.pi/n_cells)
k_y = n_y * (2*np.pi/n_cells)
k_z = n_z * (2*np.pi/n_cells)
G = np.zeros( [n_cells, n_cells, n_cells] )
for i in range(n_cells ):
    fft_kx = k_x[i]
    for j in range( n_cells ):
        fft_ky = k_y[j]
        for k in range( n_cells ):
            fft_kz = k_z[k]
            G[k,j,i] = np.exp( -0.5 * sigma**2 * ( fft_kx**2 + fft_ky**2 + fft_kz**2 ) )
fft_dens = np.fft.fftn(density)
fft_conv = G*fft_dens
dens = np.real(np.fft.ifftn(fft_conv))
return dens



The result looks fine, but maybe someone could show me better/faster approach. Also, can you recommend me some books/articles, where can I find the expressions of various functions in the Fourier space.
